# matlab, images are the same size but I can't use imabsdiff

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to use **imabsdiff** in matlab to find the difference between two images.
when I use it I have this error on the terminal (X and Y are the images)

> X and Y must be the same size.

but my problem is that when I use **size** function for checking the size of images one of them is *512, 512* and another one is *512, 512, 3*

I have no idea about this, what should I do? :(

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like one of the images is grayscale and the other is colour (3 channels).  One solution is to make both images grayscale `rgb2gray` and then run `imabsdiff`

```
imgA = ...;   % The 3 channel image (size [512, 512, 3])
imgB = ...;   % The single channel image (size [512, 512])
imabsdiff(rgb2gray(imgA), imgB);
```